# Read Oracle BLOB type via SQL

Tags: oracle-10g

I have an oracle table with field type BLOB, length 4000, data type "2004".
I know that this field simply contains some XML.  How can I read the value of the BLOB, using an SQL select statement?  Is there some conversion function to use?
The same table/field in Sql Server is simply text.

Comment: Why is this a BLOB (binary) column in Oracle and a text column in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

This oracle package will do the job

select dbms_lob.substr(b,2000,1) from blobtest;